# Is it possible to reset the Face ID permission alert for an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, face-id, localauthentication

The first time you try to use Face ID for an app a system permission alert prompt is shown "Do you want to allow  to use Face ID" (like Photos, Contacts etc permissions). However, there appears to be no way to reset this.

I've tried deleting the app and re-installing, and even resetting Face ID on my phone. But once I re-install the app the Face ID permission is already enabled for the app in `Settings -> Face ID` and in `Settings -> <app>`, and when I attempt to use Face ID it works right away, without the permission prompt appearing.

Seems like a bug. To be clear, this is an app I'm running on my iPhone X via Xcode, not an App Store app (I don't know if that makes a difference, it shouldn't).

Using a new Bundle ID each time to test this seems a little drastic

Comment: Unfortunately, that’s how all iOS permissions works. Deleting the app and waiting 2 days before reinstalling also works.

Comment: @Daniel nope, Photos and Notifications permissions are reset after app re-install. I know because I do that all the time. I assume the same is the case for all other permissions except Face ID.

Comment: It s definitely the same behaviour for camera and location services

Comment: Have you tried reseting "Location & Privacy"? I've used it to test calendar access permissions, maybe it works for face ID as well.

Comment: I'am facing exactly the same issue. I have even reset the iPhone to factory settings in order to get a fresh platform, but Face ID is still disabled with my app (only). I suspect that this behaviour is related to a combination app ID / app name as defined in Xcode. I will wait 2 days as Daniel suggest. Stay tuned.

Comment: @gdorbes apparently `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy` does the trick, but I haven't tried it yet for fear of other collateral damage :)

Comment: @mluisbrown As a did a complete reset with no result, I guess that resetting only location and privacy will not be enough. I will see.

Comment: @mluisbrown please add your `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy` trick as an answer, and feel free to accept it. I have just verified that it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy` this resets the Face ID permission alert.